# Is file://. a valid URI?

Tags: xml, uri

I expect this to mean "the current directory" which of course is meaningless on another machine or even at a different time, but it's triggering a schema error on Xerces and I think it's wrong to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't. A file protocol has two parts, a host and a path. If you omit the host, the slash is still required. Yours is just a path. `file:///.` would probably be acceptable, but not what you are looking for. A file protocol is completely unaware of the current directory. That would expand to `file://localhost/.`, which would mean a directory or file named `.` on the current system, as cHao noted in the comments.

> Note that when omitting host you do not omit the slash ("file:///foo.txt" is okay, while "file://foo.txt" is not, although some interpreters manage to handle the latter)
>
> [Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

Comment: Course, it'd probably refer to a directory named `.` at the root of the drive.

Comment: OK, what about `file://./foo`? Is that saying '.' is the host?